# Rupee icon is not showing in chrome windows

Tags: windows, html, css, google-chrome

rupee icon is not showing in chrome windows.I am using following code , correct me if am doing wrong

## my code

## html

```
<span class="rupee">
        <input type="text" />
    </span>
```

---

### css

```
.rupee {
         position: relative;
     }
     .rupee input {
         padding-left:18px;
     }
     .rupee:before {
         position: absolute;
         top: 0;
         content:"₹";
         left: 5px;
         color:red;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Download the web rupee font and all font files from the internet. these are the need files for all the browsers

```
WebRupee.V2.0.eot,WebRupee.V2.0.ttf,WebRupee.V2.0.woff,WebRupee.V2.0.svg.
```

and call the font as per below code and give class to any html tag.
please check the following example.

```
@font-face{font-family:WebRupee;src:url('WebRupee.V2.0.eot');src:local('WebRupee'),url('WebRupee.V2.0.ttf') format('truetype'),url('WebRupee.V2.0.woff') format('woff'),url('WebRupee.V2.0.svg') format('svg');font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;}

.rupee { font-family: WebRupee; }

<span class="rupee">Rs.</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using font for icons then please make sure you've included all fonts extension, **.eot, .ttf, .svg, .woff**

different extension works for different browser,
in other way you can use image for rupee sign..

Answer (score 0):

Its a Issue with Chrome (in Windows 10)...
Under

> chrome://flags/#disable-direct-write

ENABLE - "Disable-DirectWrite" 
Then Restart your Browser